# How to define permission sets in web application in python flask?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, user-permissions

I am making a web applicaion in python with flask framework in which different types of users are there like admin, editior, normal user etc. So the application access is different for each. How to implement this?. After login application need to redirect to user related views . Please help to make this in a better way

Comment: Do you have any code you can post, or did you make any progress? If not, here is the link that will show you how to start implementing an authorization framework in flask http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/98/.

Comment: You can use Casbin together with the Flask middleware: https://github.com/pycasbin/flask-authz

Answer (score 0):

There is a Flask extension **[Flask-RBAC](https://flask-rbac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)** which does exactly what you need:

> Flask-RBAC provides a Role-based Access Control module in Flask
>   applications. It can help you to control different role of users to
>   access your website.

Comment: how to implement the url redirection for each user types. i mean if its an admin it should route to /settings . or if its an user it should go to /index.

Comment: I tried to use the RBAC . but the permissions is not working. its saying all users has permissions i checked rbac.has_permission('POST', 'admin.user_list') its always returning True for all users . i used models as in the documentations. But its not working. didnt get the actual logic of this RBAC_USE_WHITE.

Comment: @Prasobhraj do you solve the problem. I find it pretty hard to do RBAC in Flask ..and in the flask-rbac ,roles even don't have permission to assign which is ridiculous..

Comment: @tyan no i didnt . Then I used Flask-Principal to play with permission set

Comment: @Prasobhraj me too,Seems we are using the same approach.I store needs in the database then use flask pricipal to do the Permission thing..